# Python program Terminated due to timeout - HackerRank

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to solve a question from HackerRank and when I submit my solution, I get an error stating "Terminated due to timeout".

Please check the code and suggest me how to optimize.

**Question:**
A left rotation operation on an array of n size shifts each of the array's elements 1 unit to the left. For example, if 2 left rotations are performed on array [1,2,3,4,5], then the array would become [3,4,5,1,2].

Given an array of n integers and a number,d, perform d left rotations on the array. Then print the updated array as a single line of space-separated integers.

**Input Format**

The first line contains two space-separated integers denoting the respective values of n (the number of integers) and d (the number of left rotations you must perform). 
The second line contains  space-separated integers describing the respective elements of the array's initial state.

**Output Format**

Print a single line of n space-separated integers denoting the final state of the array after performing d left rotations.

**Sample Input**

5 4
1 2 3 4 5

**Sample Output**

5 1 2 3 4

**Explanation**

When we perform d = 4 left rotations

Thus, we print the array's final state as a single line of space-separated values, which is 5 1 2 3 4.

**My Code:**

```
def array_left_rotation(ar, n, k):
    for j in range(k):
        temp = ar[0]
        for i in range(0,n-1):
            ar[i] = ar[i+1]
        ar[n-1] = temp
    return ar
n, k = map(int, input().strip().split(' '))
a = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
answer = array_left_rotation(a, n, k);
print(*answer, sep=' ')
```

Comment: Instead of shifting the array by one place at a time in a large loop, you could use Python's array slicing: `a[k:] + a[:k]`.

Comment: @MOehm , it is better to slice for `k % n`. Have explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46349877/7550472)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the best way is not to actually perform the operations yourself. In this case you are manually rotating the list and that is unnecessary computation.

So first, analyze the problem and how it behaves for various outputs. So lets analyze :

Suppose for an Array of 5 elements

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If you **rotate** this `2 times`, you get :

```
[3,4,5,1,2]
```

Now, try the same for rotation with `7 times` on the original array. You again get :

```
[3,4,5,1,2]
```

Similar trials will see the pattern emerge. ie, for a **rotation** of `k times`, it is same as `k % n times`.

Now that we have that with us, move to the computation part. For that, simply use `list slicing` to get the rotation, like this :

```
#n -> number of elements in array
#k -> number of rotations to be performed
#a -> (list) array

def rotate(a,n,k) :
    rotations = k % n
    new_array = a[rotations:] + a[:rotations]

    return new_array
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a[2:] + a[:2]
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
>>> ' '.join(str(i) for i in (a[2:] + a[:2]))
'3 4 5 1 2'
>>>
>>> def rotate_list(array, d):
...    return array[d:] + array[:d]
>>>
>>> ' '.join(str(i) for i in rotate_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4))
... '5 1 2 3 4'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
number_of_elements = int(input("Enter the number of elements to be inserted in array:"))
rotations = int(input("Enter the number of rotations:"))
array = []
for i in range(number_of_elements):
    number = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    array.append(number)

array = array[rotations:] + array[:rotations]
print(*array, end=' ')
```